# how to find header footer from pdf files

Tags: c#, java, c++, .net, pdf

I want to find/extract the header or footer from pdf file. 
I know it can be done by apose.net library but it is not free. I searched internet but cound not find a free library for extracting header or footer.

> Many library like itextsharp can just add header or footer but not
>   extract or find header or footer.

I do not find any method to extract the header or footer.

How can i do it?

Comment: what language is this question in?

Comment: May be any language. @LaiXinChu

Comment: @lai xin chu--- language is not matter. I just want the way to find header or footer as text/string. 
I wonder what is the problem with language? If someone is a good programmer then he can easily understand the procedures in any programming languages.
and only for you I know java/c# and c++.

Comment: just asking in case sample code is provided. relax. you have to consider the availablity of libraries too.

Comment: Technically PDF doesn't contain Header/Footer

Comment: @dilipkumbham  you do not know about pdf. see adobe's specification about pdf. just google it. you will find

Answer (score 0):

Headers and Footer should have the same structure on whole document, so I think is good way to start with. You can **search** for some **pattern** and then extract the Header / Footer. Then you can use libraries like `itextsharp` to extract this values, usefull method:

`PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, fromPage, toPage);`

Comment: I have already use this method. I have a pdf which has several blank page but from that page i get some text by GetTextFromPage() method.
And the text from all blank page are not same. so i can not use search method on particular pattern.